# Pandas: add columns that show values from previous day, week, month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have made a dataframe. Please see the image below.

[image: dataframe_sample_image]

I'd like to add columns that show values from previous day, week, month.
My expected output would be such as ***P1_day, P1_yesterday, P1_week, P1_lastweek, P1_month, P1_lastmonth*** and so on.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot use shift() since date is not unique.

Comment: It's easier to help if you paste in a text version of your dataset rather than a screenshot as then others can use `pd.read_clipboard()` to reproduce the dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your aversion to using shift, but considering you have a data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

original = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), columns=["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"])
```

you can always shift column wise such as:

```
original["P1_yesterday"] = original["P1_day"].shift()
```

or alternatively subset all the columns you want to shift, shift and rename them and then concatenate them to the original data frame such as:

```
subset_shifted = original[["P1_day", "P1_week", "P1_month"]].shift()
subset_shifted.columns = ["P1_yesterday", "P1_lastweek", "P1_lastmonth"]
original = pd.concat([original, subset_shifted], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using `shift` you could use the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) library.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.relativedelta as rd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.datetime(2019,5,1),pd.datetime(2019,5,2),pd.datetime(2019,5,3)]})

df
        Date
0 2019-05-01
1 2019-05-02
2 2019-05-03
```

Then use the `dateutil` to get new dates

```
df['P1_yesterday'] = df['Date'].dt.date + rd.relativedelta(days=-1)
df['P1_lastweek'] = df['Date'].dt.date + rd.relativedelta(weeks=-1)
df['P1_lastmonth'] = df['Date'].dt.date + rd.relativedelta(months=-1)
df

        Date P1_yesterday P1_lastweek P1_lastmonth
0 2019-05-01   2019-04-30  2019-04-24   2019-04-01
1 2019-05-02   2019-05-01  2019-04-25   2019-04-02
2 2019-05-03   2019-05-02  2019-04-26   2019-04-03
```

*I had to take the extra step to convert to datetime columns for some reason, maybe someone can modify the code to make it simpler*

```
df.P1_lastweek = pd.to_datetime(df.P1_lastweek)
df.P1_yesterday = pd.to_datetime(df.P1_yesterday)
df.P1_lastmonth = pd.to_datetime(df.P1_lastmonth)
```

Now, you can use the accessors if necessary to get just the number if that's what you need.

```
df.P1_lastweek.dt.day

0    24
1    25
2    26
Name: P1_lastweek, dtype: int64
```